# How to detect USB disconnect while blocking reading?

Tags: c, linux, arduino, io, serial-port

I am quite new to this stuff, so be aware. I want to read a single char from an arduino. Therefore I have enabled the serial communication on the arduino with a baud rate of 9600 (more than enough for my needs). This following code works - sometimes. Sometimes I read the correct data and sometimes I get some invaid characters. Also there is the problem that if the device is initialized but then the USB is disconnected (for example just pull the cable), this program does not terminate. What am I doing wrong?

```
int main() {
int fd = open("/dev/ArduinoDeviceName", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(fd < 0) {
    printf("Failed to connect to device!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
struct termios SerialPortSettings;
tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings); 
cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600); 
cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600); 
if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) {
    printf("Error while setting attributes \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
printf("Init done!\n");


printf("read: _%c_", read_next_char(fd));
close(fd);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

EDIT 1:
Now with some additional settings I could achieve to read the correct data values, see code below:

```
char read_next_char(int fd) {
char buffer[1] = {0};
fcntl(fd,  F_SETFL);
switch (read(fd, &buffer, sizeof(buffer))) {
    case 1: printf("Read bytes correct!\n"); break;
    case 0: printf("Reached EOF\n"); break;
    case -1: printf("Error occured while reading!\n"); break;
    default: break;
};
return buffer[0];
}


int main() {
int fd = open("/dev/tty.usbmodem14101", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);
if(fd < 0) {
    printf("Failed to connect to device!\n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
struct termios SerialPortSettings;
tcgetattr(fd, &SerialPortSettings);
cfsetispeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
cfsetospeed(&SerialPortSettings,B9600);
SerialPortSettings.c_iflag=0;
SerialPortSettings.c_oflag=0;
SerialPortSettings.c_cflag=CS8|CREAD|CLOCAL;
SerialPortSettings.c_lflag=0;
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VMIN]=1;
SerialPortSettings.c_cc[VTIME]=5;

if((tcsetattr(fd,TCSANOW,&SerialPortSettings)) != 0) {// Set the attributes to the termios structure
    printf("Error while setting attributes \n");
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}
printf("Init done!\n");

char read;
while((read = read_next_char(fd)) != 0) {
    printf("Correctly read: _%c_", read);
}
close(fd);
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

The only thing that sometimes can be annoying is, that the arduino sends some data via serial in a loop with some delay. If the computer connects there are always some data sent, before the arduino resets. How can I achieve that the arduino / serial port gets reset before I read any data?

Comment: You should set the tty to raw mode (non-canonical mode), so the tty layer does not modify the data passed from the arduino to your program.  As to *why* you're having a problem, without seeing `read_next_char()` others can only guess.

Comment: added the latest program, my bad. I though that I also copied the read_next_char ^^

Comment: You should use `TCSAFLUSH` instead of `TCSANOW`, because you want to discard any already buffered data, previously sent from the Arduino.  Which Arduino board are you using?  I know how to do this with native USB; I don't use boards with an UART bridge.

Comment: That was a good point! Now it works like a charm. I am currently using an Arduino Nano, works like a charm. For the end result I will create a custom pcb with custom schematic.

Comment: Your (revised) termios initialization code is not POSIX compliant, and may not work in every situation.  See [Setting Terminal Modes Properly](http://www.chemie.fu-berlin.de/chemnet/use/info/libc/libc_12.html#SEC237)
and [Serial Programming Guide for POSIX Operating Systems](http://www.cmrr.umn.edu/~strupp/serial.html).  The `fcntl(fd,  F_SETFL);` statement in **read_next_char()** is (a) misplaced because it does not need to be called for every read syscall, and (b) has an incomplete argument list (& should have generated a compiler error).

Comment: Linux doesn't buffer the data received for an unopened serial port, so `TCSAFLUSH` should not make a difference compared to `TCSANOW`.  IOW how much data do you expect to receive in the microsecond(s) between the **open()** and **tcsetattr()**?  *"How can I achieve that the arduino / serial port gets reset before I read any data?"* -- What does this have to do with the title subject?  What is the problem?